# The report has no tables error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset

This is my code:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet1
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim con1 As String = "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM POBasket where POBNumber='" + txtorderno.Text + "'"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(con1)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
    Dim dscrystal As New DataSet1
    dscmd.Fill(dscrystal, "POBasket")
    cnn.Close()

    Dim report As CrystalReport1 = New CrystalReport1
    report.SetDataSource(dscrystal.Tables("POBasket"))
    report.SetParameterValue("ProductName", "+")
    poreport.pocrystalviewer.ReportSource = report
    poreport.pocrystalviewer.Refresh()
    poreport.Show()
```

I always get the error :

> *The report has no tables*

Please help me!

Comment: It would have been nice if you actually posted some feedback on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671504/create-crystal-report-programmatically) you asked rather than asking a new question. At least I would have known that my answer was somewhat faulty.

Comment: sorry about that. I have tried it, but it didn't work. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below:

```
report.database.table[0].setdatasource(dscrystal.Tables("POBasket"))
```

instead of

```
report.SetDataSource(dscrystal.Tables("POBasket"))
```

Its work for me.

I think it will help you.